# Can't login to Ubuntu 16.04 lts after using software updater

Tags: login, update-manager

I hope that you guys can help me. I'm a newbie. After using Software Updater on my Ubuntu Desktop, I was stuck in a login loop. I browsed the askubuntu forums but I came up with nothing.

My graphics card is Nvidia GT 1030.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: did you change the video driver?? look in the link posted by Charles for directions on reverting it.

Comment: I installed an nvidia driver for my nvidia gt 1030 and I have checked the link.  I was unable to use 'chown username:username .Xauthority' and I used 'dpkg-reconfigure light' but I still could not login. I was unable to open '.xsession-errors', I tried '~/.xsession-errors' but it said "permission denied" and I tried 'sudo ~/.xsession-errors' but it said "command not found".

Comment: did you install a third party driver? IE from nVidia? right now I would say the problem is an incorrect driver.  Note: kernels 4.4 and newer will not load third party driver if secure boot is on, unless you have signed them.

Comment: @ravery I installed Nvidia 389.54, it worked fine until I used software updater.

Comment: @user748896 -- and what did you update?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after some Xorg component (server?) update yesterday. Reinstalling the Nvidia driver fixed the problem.

Comment: I reinstalled the Nvidia driver and I got a black screen.